# unconverted data remains for only some of records

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset including timestamps that some of them have decimals in seconds, but some don't. I need to compare these timestamps and classify those. I don't know how to define the format differently for these records.

So, for those which have decimals in seconds, I can write:

```
a = datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

and for those which don't have, I write:

```
a = datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

I need to compare *a* to another timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string.split function to separate the string into 3 fields, and see if the third one has a ".".  You might want more error handling than I have provided here.

```
def has_seconds(a_string):
    return "." in a_string.split(":")[2]

if has_seconds(a_time):
    a = datetime.strptime(a_time, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
else:
    a = datetime.strptime(a_time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to remove the decimals, so all of them are now in a same format.